# How to implement twice MATLAB integral build-in function for numeric integration?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, approximate-integration

Suppose we have a function $F(\lambda) = \int\limits_{\lambda}^1 f(x) dx$, where $f(x)$ has no formula for antiderivative.

We can easily calculate it by means of build-in MATLAB functions. Let's use $f(x) =\sqrt{x}e^{-x}$ for example:

```
>>f = @(x) sqrt(x) .* exp(-x);
>>F = @(lambda) integral(@(x) f(x), lambda, 1);
F(0.3)
ans = 
    0.2028
```

What if we need to find $G(\mu) = \int\limits_0^{\mu} F(\lambda)d{\lambda}$ now?

I tried to use the same approach and write

```
G = @(mu) integral(F, 0, mu)
```

but MATLAB returns an error in this case. As far as I understood, MATLAB expects function handle as the first argument of an *integral* function, but we obtain a number instead. Is there a way to handle this problem?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: By "not integrable" do you mean not having a nice formula for the antiderivative? You might change the language as nonintegrability is a different concept. Also, maybe try using other variables names instead of all $x$'s. That probably won't fix it, but will make it easier to read. E.g. $\int_0^x \int_y^1 f(t) dt dy$.

Comment: You should not use the same variable $x$ for two different purposes in the same formula.  If $x$ is an endpoint, it shouldn't be the variable of integration.

Comment: @jdods, yes, I meant that. I'll fix it. I tried your way of writing it, but it doesn't work as we have a numbers after first integration (as I understood), but we have to have function handle instead.

Comment: @Robert Israel, when I write $x$ in both places a mean that I have a variable integration limit. So, when calculating, for instance $F(0.3)$, I have $\int\limits_{0.3}^1  f(x)dx$. So, it is not OK in view of Math, but MATLAB understands my inquiry.

Comment: Your problem seems to be more succinctly explained by code like integral(@(b) integral(@(x) exp(x),0,b),0,1) (which one would expect to compute $\int_0^1 \int_0^b e^x dx db)$. It seems like in this case the code cannot ensure that the "b" being passed in from the outer function is a scalar, and so an error is raised. I'm not sure why that doesn't happen in the one-variable case then...

Comment: At any rate, this can be done more efficiently using integral2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that if you attempt to pass a vector to the inner "integral" function, it fails, but this is how the outer "integral" function wants to use its first argument. A simple workaround for the double (or analogously triple) integral case is to just use integral2. In your example this would be:

```
f=@(x,y) sqrt(x).*exp(-x);
G=@(mu) integral2(f,0,mu,@(x) x,1);
G(0.3)
```

Comment: thank you! ! It gives some idea how to handle it. There is some problems, however. If I change the order of integration, then integral2 doesn't want to see $x$ as the first argument again, ending up with raised error. So, the result of the integration doesn't seem to be correct. For instance, $f(x,y) = x$. Then $F(x) = \frac{1-x^2}{2}$, and $G(x) = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6}$ in my case. If I use your way of calculation, I shall firstly obtain the outer integral, which is $1-x$, then it is multilplied by inner integrand $f(x) = x$ and integrated, ending up with $ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$.

Comment: integral2 wants the order of integration to be dy dx. You need to reorder your variables to change it.

Comment: As I've understood my problem was to find 'G=@(mu) integral2(f,@(x)x,1,0,mu);' If I do that MATLAB complains again.

Comment: @IR55 The 2nd and 3rd arguments must be scalars. The 4th and 5th arguments can be functions. This means that to integrate the other way, you need to change f. (And you are right, you need to integrate the other way.)

Comment: To be honest, I don't see any way to change function f so that it can be calculated by means of MATLAB.  I tried to use G = @(l1,l2) integral2(f,l1,1,0,l2) but it is not what have to find, because it is not equivalent to the first task.

Comment: @IR55 Change to f=@(x,y) sqrt(y).*exp(-y) and then proceed.

Comment: For f=@(x,y)y and f = @(x,y) y.^2. G = @(mu) integral2(f,0,mu,@(x)x,1) produces the right answer. Great thank you!